# What is the relationship between the matrices obtained through Vandermonde decomposition of a Hankel matrix and the matrices obtained through its SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let **H=SBT'** be the Vandermonde decomposition of Hankel matrix H. (S and T are Vandermonde matrices.) Let **H=PDQ'** be its SVD. Is it possible to prove that P=SG? Can a similar relationship be established between matrices Q and T?

Comment: What is G here?

Comment: G is a nonsingular square matrix of the same size as P and S. (It is assumed that H is  a square matrix.)